# Passing a variable from a list as part of calling a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, soap, salesforce

I am using `SimpleSalesforce` and would like to use the `describe()` function. An example of that is `sf.Contact.describe()` to describe the Contact record. I would like to loop through several records in a list, but I'm not sure how to pass in a variable in place of Contact.

```
Objects = ['Contact','Opportunity']
for object in Objects:
    print sf.object.describe()
```

This yields an error of:

```
simple_salesforce.api.SalesforceResourceNotFound: Resource object Not Found. Response content: [{u'errorCode': u'NOT_FOUND', u'message': u'The requested resource does not exist'}]
```

Comment: Please make the question . More understandable . What you intended to ask in not clear. Post details in a way that it is helpful to others too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

object is a string in this example. You can retrieve the attribute using `getattr`

```
Objects = ["Contact", "Opportunity"]
for object in Objects: # object is a string.
    print getattr(sf, object).describe()
```

Comment: Should also mention here that `Objects` and `object` are not good names for things. see [PEP-8#Naming](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a list of objects instead of a list of strings, then you can invoke the `describe` method off of those objects

```
Objects = [sf.Contact, sf.Opportunity]
for object in Objects:
    print object.describe()
```

Comment: This works if you remove the `sf.` from the print line and fix your typo in line 1 :). Thanks,

Comment: @user2242044 It's late and I'm out of coffee :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Objects = ['Contact','Opportunity']
for object in Objects:
    if object == 'Contact':
        print sf.Contact.describe()
    elif object == 'Opportunity':
        print sf.Opportunity.describe()
```

Comment: This is great for the simplified example, but in reality it may loop through a list of several hundred elements.